# Unit Testing when using EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

For the project I am doing in my internship we have to use a repository pattern. Since the project was already using EF Core and I read that there was already repository and unit of work in the underlying implementation. I figured I would just use the EF Core methods directly without implementing repository classes as I wanted to prevent clutter.

Well now I am in a bit of a problem, I can't seem to find much useful information on unit testing when I implement this way. The requirement is a hard requirement, and I required 100% coverage of CRUD functions within my controllers due to the standards of this firm. I found some of the Microsoft Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test?view=aspnetcore-2.1), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-2.1), and the integration testing [using SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite) but I still can't seem to figure out unit testing. I did some googling as well and I can't find resources aside from integration testing.

Is there some way I can unit test using EF Core directly, or am I gonna have to make repositories in order to properly unit test this program?

Comment: You simply make a test project in the same solution and create acreference to your EF project. Theb start writting you CRUD test methods.

Comment: Wouldn't that be an integration test though, as its testing the components used in the controllers as well?

Comment: It is still a valid unittest going to db testing the chain and CRUD. Integrated testing is on a higher level. If you realy do not want to go to db and you have logic you need to test you can use mock objects. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/fundamental-of-unit-testing-understand-mock-object-in-unit/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you do not have a separate repository, you do not have to unit test your repository; you cannot unit test what you don’t have.

What you would usually test with EF Core would be actual database access. For that, you can use the [in-memory database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) to temporarily set up your database which you can run full tests against. Of course, this is more an integration test than a minimal unit test.

But you should think about this: When you write unit tests, you have to have an actual idea of what you are testing. Just saying “I need unit tests for component X” does not make real sense. Usually, it would be more like “I need unit tests for methods U, W, Y of component X”. So unless you actually have methods with real behavior that you need to test, attempting to write unit tests for the database context just makes no sense.

You only want to unit test things things that you write yourself. If there’s nothing, e.g. because you are using the direct database context functionalities for CRUD, then there’s nothing to test. The EF Core project is already covering their side with unit tests, and you probably don’t want to start unit testing third party code here.

Comment: When using in-memory database a case could be made that it is a unit test.  The tests have no external process dependencies and run very fast.  In-memory is not a real database engine (it uses IMemoryCache).  No database connections are made and constraints or referential integrity are not checked.

Comment: @Brad Yeah, it’s a gray area. Technically, it isn’t really a unit since you are involving more components than just the one you are testing. – But yeah, I personally use the in-memory database like unit tests as well.

Comment: if instead of "unit" or "integration" you categorize tests based on "slowness" and "configuration complexity", then you will abstract only things which makes tests slow or complex. In small application you will be able to have fast tests which covers whole application "pipeline". Which will provide safety net and freedom in refactoring and internal design updates. "In-Memory" database provide perfect tool for this approach.

Answer (score 4):

With EF Core you may use InMemoryDatabase, mock data of your DbContext and test your methods against this data.

Repository adds additional abstraction layer and makes testing a bit more transparent, but it is also possible to inject DbContext with mocked data for your unit tests.

[Some code to illustrate an idea](https://github.com/anton-danylov/EFCoreWebinar/blob/UnitTestingWithInMemoryDB/BloggingEFCore/Tests/DataAccessTests.cs)

Just don't forget to check is InMemoryDatabase was already passed to the context and do not add another provider in that case.

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("ConnectionString");
        }
```

[Tip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory)

If you are using ASP.NET Core, then you should not need this code since your database provider is already configured outside of the context (in Startup.cs).